# std::span<const T> as parameter in function template

Tags: c++, c++20

In the following library functions `f` and `g`, I use `std::span<const T>` to remind the user of the library of the contract that `f` and `g` will not modify the contents of the span. The user of the library holds `std::span<int> a`, which is convertible to `std::span<const int>`. Hence, the user can call `g(a)` as expected. However, the user cannot call `f(a)`, since `f` is a function template and `a` is not of the required type; conversions do not apply here. Can you see a (sane) way to have `f` take in `std::span<const T>` while still accepting `std::span<T>`?

```
#include <span>

void g(const std::span<const int>& a) {}

template <typename T>
void f(const std::span<const T>& a) {}

int main()
{
    std::span<int> a;
    // OK
    g(a);
    // No match
    f(a);
    // OK
    f((std::span<const int>)a);
}
```

It is possible to add an overload like this:

```
template <typename T>
void f(const std::span<T>& a) {
    return f((std::span<const T>)a);
}
```

But I'm not sure if I count this as sane, since then I would be writing these overloads to every function template which takes in `std::span<const T>`.

EDIT: Not the same case, but if `f` also happens to take in another parameter which mentions `T`, then one can do the following:

```
template <typename T> using NoDeduction = std::type_identity_t<T>;

template <typename T>
void f(NoDeduction<std::span<const T>> a, const T& b) {}
```

After which `f(a, 1);` works. This is a partial solution. The original problem still remains.

EDIT 2: I was wondering whether the above technique works also when we include span's compile-time size:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void f(const std::span<NoDeduction<const T>, N>& a, const T& b) {}
```

Gcc 10.1 compiles it, MSVC 16.6.2 and Clang 10.0.0 don't. I filed bug reports for both MSVC and Clang.

Comment: I've been stuck on a similar problem (Clang 17). I've been debugging this all day to the point where I don't even know how to describe this problem anymore. I originally started replacing all the bare pointer usage in my code base with std::span and now the templates don't event compile... Things are just so much easier with bare pointers...

Answer (score 4):

You can generalize your overload to be a **utility** like `std::as_const`:

```
template<class T>
std::span<const T> const_span(std::span<T> s) {return s;}
```

The caller then has to decorate their calls with mutable spans, but in so doing indicates to the reader that no modification is allowed.

Another, unconventional workaround would be to make your function be a class and use **deduction guides**:

```
template<class T>
struct f {
  f(std::span<const T>);
  // operator ReturnType();
};
template<class T> f(std::span<T>)->f<T>;
```

It’s debatable whether the interface describes the intent here.

Comment: That deduction guide is a nice find. Interestingly, `std::span<int> a; f(a);` fails to compile, because it is interpreted as a redeclaration of variable `a`.

Comment: @kaba: Indeed; you have to do something silly like add extra parentheses.

Comment: Why is there not a conversion from span<T> to span <const T> as it exists for all stl iterators?

Comment: @Oliv: There is, but just like the standard qualification conversion you sometimes need to invoke it explicitly because the desired type can’t be determined from context.

Comment: This answer is confusing because it provides two answers, one bad, one worse. I marked it an answer cuz - it maybe just the best answer given how the language works. const_span maybe acceptable. Another approach is just to NOT declare your public APIs with span <const T> - just use span<T>. Really - this is a Horrible limitation of span. And the just want to say the function object / deduction guide option is a crazy non-starter. NOT viable (if you have thouands of function defs to do that for each?).

Answer (score 0):

It is unable to make the type conversion because it fails to deduce the type as `f` is a template.

If you want to write template function `f` that accepts various input types - you'd better write it as

```
 template<typename Viewer>
 void f(const Viewer& a){...}
```

If you want to work with `span` then you can implement it in two steps:

```
 template<typename T>
 void f_impl(std::span<const T> a){...}

 template<typename Viewer>
 void f(const Viewer& a)
 {
      f_impl(std::span<const typename Viewer::value_type>(a.data(),a.size()));
  }
```

P.S. with `span` you should normally take copy of it instead of "const reference". This is more efficient.

Comment: The intent was to have the function signature to tell the user that the parameter is `std::span`, and that the contents of the span will not be modified. While this solution protects the implementer from accidentally modifying the contents, it hides the information about the interface from the user. I wonder if C++ is currently lacking expressiveness to deal with this problem properly.

Comment: @kaba it is very complicated to deal with templates in general.  Imagine a complicated case with a bunch of tuples. Thus the general solution is to analyze input parameter and act accordingly. With concepts it'll be possible to do it more conviniently but still the correct thing is to require that input type satisfies certain criteria instead of restricting it to `span`.